# Does Athena use SparkSQL?If not then what does it use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql

How do I understand if it is SparkSQL. Spark documentation says SparkSQL has dataframes but if I have MS SQL Server code , how do I convert into SparkSQL for running successfully on AWS?Total Beginner here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Athena is Amazon's version of PrestoDB, it is not the same as Spark. Athena data is stored in an S3 bucket, so you would usually have Spark load the data out of the bucket directly rather than querying through Athena.

Answer (score 0):

[Athena now also has Spark](https://www.infoq.com/news/2023/01/amazon-athena-apache-spark/).

This is new, optional functionality.